# Create a class containing data without user input?

Tags: python, class, object, store

I have recently started my end of the year project in computer science (self proposed, also my first year taking it so only have about 4 months of python experience) and decided I wanted to do a simple Pokemon simulator in it.

I've recently run into a roadblock: Let's say the user chooses Pikachu as their starter. I don't want the user to input their health, attack, speed, and moves. Is their a way to create a Pikachu class that already has that data in it?

I tried something like this:

```
class Pikachu(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
    def health(self):
        self.health = 22
        print self.health
    def attack(self):
        self.attack = 7
    def speed(self):
        self.speed = 6

Pikachu.health()
```

When I do this (in an attempt to check and see if the health is stored and will be returned on demand), it gives the error:

> TypeError: unbound method health() must be called with Pikachu instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

I'm confused as to what the error means as well. Usually this would work and you wouldn't need an argument in the parentheses, but in this instance it doesn't.

Is there some different way to create a class and store data in it? Is there some way to just create an object or do something like this:

```
def Pikachu:
    health = 22
    attack = 7
    speed = 6
```

Comment: `Pikachu().health()`...

Comment: Well that was a dumb error on my part! Thanks for the very quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

it is because your variable names are the same as your method names. and also why don't you initialise everything in the constructor:

```
    class Pikachu(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.attack = 7
        self.health = 22
        self.speed = 6
    def get_health(self):
        return self.health

    def get_attack(self):
         return self.attack

    def get_speed(self):
         return self.speed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pikachu()
    print p.get_health()
```